# python - how register user with xmpp

Tags: python, linux, xmpp

I'm trying to register a new user, but not work. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Client instance has no attribute 'SendAndWaitForResponse'
```

this is my code:

```
import xmpp, sys
usuario = 'test1@localhost'
password = 'mypassword'
jid = xmpp.JID(usuario)
cli = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(), debug=[])
cli.connect()

if xmpp.features.register(cli,jid.getDomain(),{'username':jid.getNode(),'password':password}):
    sys.stderr.write('Success\n')
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.stderr.write('Error\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

i use linux

Comment: Before answering your question, will need to know which xmpp library you are using and what xmpp server you are connecting to?

Comment: I use Python-xmpp and I try to connect to my machine

Comment: Do you have a xmpp server installed and running locally? e.g. jabberd, prosody, etc.

Comment: Oh, I'm new and I don't have prosody. I will install, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also met this issue. When you remove "debug=[]" from the connect param list. You can get the debug output. In my side, this issue is because the server can not be reached.